# Android Packager: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: resources.arsc

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

I'm building an Android application in IntelliJ IDEA 12.1.4. I am using the most recent Android SDK tools as of 8/2/2013 which goes up to API level 18 for the recently released Android 4.3. My build target is Android 4.3 and my Java SDK is 1.7.

When I attempt to build my application, the build fails with the following message:

```
Error: Android Packager: [appname] java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: resources.arsc
```

I've binged and googled the exact text in the Title but could not find any references. I also tried binging and googling java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry and found some related errors, but nothing that I was able to make sense of. I've also researched what resources.arsc is and have learned that it is a file containing pre-compiled resources that sits in the .apk.

I'm not sure if when it says "duplicate entry" it means that there is a duplicate resource in resources.arsc (because I don't know how that file is built) or if it means there is a second resources.arsc that it is trying to add to the .apk resulting in the conflict.

Any insight into the parts involved will probably help me find the answer, but if you have experience resolving this, please share.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not surprisingly, I found my own answer immediately after asking this question (like buying a replacement for a lost item). Under `File>Project Structure>Platform Settings>Global Libraries` I had added the `org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE` from Maven. This included several .jar files. I removed all of them but the two that I knew to be necessary which are `spring-android-core-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar` and `spring-android-rest-template-1.0.1.RELEASE.jar`. Once I did that, the project compiled without a hitch. So for anyone else that runs into a similar problem, check your Global Libraries and make sure any Maven dependencies only include the .jars you actually need.